# Best way to sync tables of different databases

Tags: laravel, mariadb

I have 3 web applications which are hosted on 3 different servers. These 3 web applications have one table in common which is user table where web application 1's user table is the main user details. All the transaction will done here. Web App 2 & 3 's user must be synced with web app 1's user table.

I am thinking to sync this table via API where on transaction of web app1's user table, app will call api of application 2 & 3 using webhooks concept.

Is it correct way ?What are the options ? I dont want triggers as it requires more maintenance than API.

Comment: Would having a second connection be an option and set the User model connection to work from that?

Comment: @Repox: Could you please elaborate it bit more?

Comment: You could add a [second connection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections) and call it `users` and your User model could then have that connection as default by specifying that connection specifically by adding it as a property; `protected $connection = 'users';` That way, the users will always use that connection and you will never have to sync.